# Swift tableViewCell keep duplicating on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've read every thread about

```
if(cell == nil)
```

but that throws an error incomparable.  I've been trying for days to get my tableViewCells to stop duplicating when it already exists.  Someone help!!  The title in my section headers even duplicate and overlay each other.  i'm assuming my images are duplicating as well.  When i test on my iphone the scrolling is all laggy.

```
ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationItem!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var list = []
var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func getListBro() -> NSArray {
    return list
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension



    let streamURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8000/beat-stream-all/")!

    let stuff = GetBeatStream(url:streamURL)
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0; //
    stuff.downloadJSONFromURL {
        (let jsonDictionary) in
            if let jsonList = jsonDictionary["results"] as? NSArray {
                self.list = jsonList
            }


            let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
                // do some task
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    // update some UI
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
    }

}//end view did load


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("streamCell") as? StreamTableViewCell

        if let beat_cover = list[indexPath.section] as? NSDictionary {
            if let beat_cover_image = beat_cover["beat_cover"] as? String {
                cell?.beatCover.image =  UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:beat_cover_image)!)!)
            }
        }


        if let descriptionSection = list[indexPath.section] as? NSDictionary {
            if let description = descriptionSection["description"] as! NSString? {
                    cell?.beatDescription.text = description as String

                cell?.beatDescription.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        }

    }



    if let audio = list[indexPath.section] as? NSDictionary {
        if let audio_url = audio["audio"] as? String {
                cell?.url = audio_url
                cell?.buildPlayer()
        }
    }

    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return list.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

//        USERNAME
    let beatAuthorLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(55, 5, 200, 40))

    //USER PIC
    let profilePictureImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 40, 40));
    profilePictureImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
    profilePictureImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    profilePictureImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    profilePictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profilePictureImageView.frame.height/2
    profilePictureImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    profilePictureImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true


    if let userPicSection = list[section] as? NSDictionary {
        if let artist = userPicSection["artist"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let profilePic = artist["profile_pic"] as? String {
                let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:profilePic)!)!)
                profilePictureImageView.image = image;
            }
        }
    }


    if let nameSection = list[section] as? NSDictionary {
        if let name = nameSection["artist"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let adminName = name["admin_name"] as? NSString {
                beatAuthorLabel.text = adminName as String
            }
        }
    }

    let dateLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(225, 5, 200, 40))
    if let created = list[section] as? NSDictionary {
        if let date = created["created_at"] as? String {
            dateLabel.text = date as String
            dateLabel.font = UIFont(name: dateLabel.font.fontName, size: 8)

        }
    }

    let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.addSubview(beatAuthorLabel)
    header.addSubview(dateLabel)
    header.contentView.addSubview(profilePictureImageView)
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 179/255, green: 194/255, blue: 191/255, alpha:1)
    header.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    header.alpha = 1

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)! as! StreamTableViewCell
    currentCell.player.play()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let leavingCell = cell as! StreamTableViewCell
    leavingCell.player.pause()
}




}
```

Comment: is there a reason, why you ignore the row of the cell? You get your data from `list` by using the index of the section. In section `0`, every cell will get the data from `list[0]` and in section `1` from `list[1]`,... I think you wanted to use `indexPath.row`

Comment: i did indexPath.section because im trying to mimic the instagram layout where every post has its own cell header.  And as far as i know the only way to  have that style header...it must be for a section....thats why im using section